# file system vs url in php

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, vhosts

I have built a little custom framework that is based on MVC architecture and I have both BASE_URL which would be something like 'http://example.com' and ROOT which would be something like '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/WEBSITENAME/'. I am trying to get a general consensus as to which is better to use when this would be deployed to a server. I do have ssh access to the server that it would be released on. I just honestly do not know which is preferred or why. I did a lot of googling and found conflicting arguments so I thought I would ask here since I trust this community. So Anyone have thoughts on which is better and why?

Oh, if it matters we are trying to use httpd-vhost.conf to create the web directories and no .htaccess files, and we are trying to remove all mod_rewrite. Not sure if that matters, but I thought I would give the info just in case.

Thank you all for your help in advance.

EDIT** I guess I should also mention that I do not mean when I am creating links, I mean for including css sheets, or js files, or including and requiring other php files, those types of actions.

Comment: One way for internal management of files, one way for external access of said files.  It should be fairly obvious which way is best for which?

Comment: This is probably a bad fit for this site. BUt, you'd want both and you'd use them in different situations.

Comment: Imagine you're including Javascript or PHP from a HTTP address.. just image what it means..

Comment: It's exactly the same difference that exists between reading from your hard disc and downloading from the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 cases:

1. for interacting with other files on the sever's side, while the php script is still executing - operations like including / requiring other php files, fopen-ing resources and so on you use paths relative to your ROOT.
2. for including CSS, javascript, images and so on - on client side - you're going to use the BASE_URL.

For example, in PHP:

```
require_once ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'my_configuration_file.php';
```

in the HTML:

```
<img src="<?=BASE_URL;?>/img/logo.png" alt="my company">
```

But consider using an existing PHP framework. It will make your life easier and let you focus on your product / site rather than maintaing it.

Comment: perfect, that's what I was wondering about. When including the css and JS files. I don't know why but for some reason I was thinking that if I was using php to write the output then I could do something like...
<?php echo '<style href="' . ROOT . 'css/base.css'" />'; ?>